# Synchronize kindle and ipad kindle app

Tags: sync, ipad, ebook, kindle

I have a kindle paperwhite and an ipad with kindle app. I have transferred to the kindle some ebooks and documents via USB and bought some books at amazon's ebook store. I noticed that the ebooks I bought from amazon can be easily downloaded through a cloud service in the ipad. Can I use this service for storing the books I sent to my kindle via USB? I mean... I'd like to have both kindle and ipad kindle app to be synchronized, having the same books.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about portable e-readers, but not how they interface *with a computer*

Comment: Have you tried sending them to username@free.kindle.com? You should at least be able to download the book from both devices then. @Luke This is true but there is no ebook site on SX and superuser seems indeed to be the closest match.

Comment: Just because it's the closest site does not mean it is suddenly on topic @Tim

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at Send to Kindle.

http://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle

It will upload to amazon servers and be available on all your kindle devices, i frequently use this to transfer technical documentation to my Ipad and kindle as a backup.